# How to set username and password from database in Ranorex?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, ranorex

I'm new in Test automation and would like to start with Ranorex.

I am willing to make iOS/Android App test automation. In App we have login-view, so that user has to input username and password to log in into the app.
The question is, how to get "username" and "password" from SQL Database in Ranorex? or is it a good idea to get data from database? or simply add variables without getting from DB?

I want to make two different case: *1. VALID-LOGIN-data* and *2. INVALID-LOGIN-data*.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set a SQL data source in Ranorex and bind it to recording variables.

I suggest you read the following article on Ranorex web site on Data Driven testing and watch the screencast (you will save valuable time):
https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/ranorex-studio-advanced/data-driven-testing/introduction/

The section that is most relevant to your question is **Manage and assign data sources**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know how to handle encrypted password?
For better explain please read my post under:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602309/how-to-handle-data-encryption-in-ranorex