# How to handle data encryption in Ranorex?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, ranorex

I want to get encrypted-password from database for login in Android and iOS App.
I've made **Username** and **password** as **data binding** and by setting password-variable to the textField, I want the password to be converted/decrypted, to set password correctly, otherwise testcase will be always failed.

is there any built-in method/function in Ranorex for doing data encryption? If not, how to do it?

(I'm new in Ranorex and test automation.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to encrypt/decrypt. You will need to do this yourself in a code module file or recording module's user code action. You can use any third-party library to help with this if needed.